# How to create UICollectionView with varying collectionView class types established at initialization?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to create a UICollectionView that can use any type of custom collectionView class that I create and all I need to do is inject the desired class type of the cell and the UICollectionView will conform to this. However, I am getting an issue at this line:

```
private var cellID: String? = nil
private var cellType: AnyClass? = nil
private var cellObject: AnyObject? = nil

//this like is inside collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! cellType

//at this line^ I am getting the error "Cannot find type 'cellType' in scope"
```

How can I pass the cellType into the collectionView to make this more dynamic?

Comment: Swift is expecting a `UICollectionViewCell type` but you are providing it a `variable`. Therefore it does not recognize `cellType` as a `type` of `UICollectionView`

Comment: @ShawnFrank Thanks, is there some way to make the UICollectionViewCell type dynamic so I can instantiate with a multiple kinds of cells?

Comment: sure. One way is changing the cell based on a condition, for example: `if condition == true { let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCellType1 } else { let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCellType2 }`